# Logging to a MLflow Server in a Different User Directory

Tags: linux, mlflow

Suppose there is a Linux machine with a few users. If a MLFlow tracking server is set up in a users home directory, is it possible to log to this tracking server by running script in a different users home directory? Are there better ways to set up tracking server in more general manner and allow users of Linux machine to log there?

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se] or if this relates to a production system issue, [sf] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.